# iOS - Calendar standalone properies aren't capitalized

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I need to set some headers with weekdays and month symbols, for that I'm using the calendar's properties `weekdaySymbols` and `monthSymbols`. However, I wand them to be capitalized, recently I notice the calendar also has the properties `standaloneWeekdaySymbols` and `standaloneMonthSymbols`, which are the symbols to use on headers, however, they don't seem to work as I expected:

```
var calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "nl-NL")

print(calendar.weekdaySymbols)
/// OUTPUT: ["zondag", "maandag", "dinsdag", "woensdag", "donderdag", "vrijdag", "zaterdag"]

print(calendar.standaloneWeekdaySymbols)
/// OUTPUT: ["zondag", "maandag", "dinsdag", "woensdag", "donderdag", "vrijdag", "zaterdag"]

print(calendar.monthSymbols)
/// OUTPUT: ["januari", "februari", "maart", "april", "mei", "juni", "juli", "augustus", "september", "oktober", "november", "december"]

print(calendar.standaloneMonthSymbols)
/// OUTPUT: ["januari", "februari", "maart", "april", "mei", "juni", "juli", "augustus", "september", "oktober", "november", "december"]
```

Shouldn't `standalone` properties be capitalized? Am I missing something here?

---

EDITED FOR pawello2222's answer:

Then I have to point out that there is some inconsistencies with Apple's date APIs, because using `DateFormatter` with `standalone context` does yield capitalized results:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEEE")
dateFormatter.formattingContext = .standalone
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "nl_NL")

let date = Date()
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
/// OUTPUT: Dinsdag
```

I would have expected that both `DateFormatter` and `Calendar` would yield the same `standalone` formats for a specific locale.

That makes me think that, either I'm doing something wrong, or the standalone properties of the calendar are not working well.

Comment: stand alone week day is `cccc` not `EEEE`

Comment: @nikano I ran your edited code in the playground (Swift 5.1), the output is `dinsdag` which is consistent with `Calendar`. Which version of Swift are you using?

Comment: You should set your date formatter locale before setting the other properties

Answer (score 1):

They are capitalised depending on the locale (different regions may have different conventions):

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-EN")

print(calendar.standaloneWeekdaySymbols)
//prints ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
```

Looks like in `nl-NL` they are all `lowercase`.

You can always use `capitalized`:

```
print("zondag".capitalized) // prints "Zondag"
```

Comment: I just edited my question to add some more context about the behavior I found with standalone properties, and why I think there is something wrong